# TypeScript. Ожидать выполнение Observable, ожидать выполнение функции

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, promise

Есть функция

```
  async loadCurrentUser(): Promise<IUser> {
    return new Promise<IUser>(ok => {
      this.getCurrentUser()
        .subscribe(
        next => {
          alert('функция, которую нужно ждать')
          this._currentUserSource.next(next);
          ok(next)
        },
        error => {
          this._currentUserSource.next(null);
          this._logService.addError(error);
          ok(null);
        })
    });
  }
```

Она вызывается в компоненте

```
await this._accountService.loadCurrentUser();
alert('функция компонента');
```

Выход из функции происходит до того, как я загружаю информацию о пользователе (выводится сообщение "функция компонента" раньше чем "функция, которую нужно ждать"), сервер не получает запрос до закрытия сообщения. Как мне дождаться загрузки информации?

Функция `getCurrentUser` возвращает объект `Observable<IUser>`

Comment: А почему бы сразу в промис не передавать результат subscribe?

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: `return new Promise(ok => { this.getCurrentUser().subscribe(next => ok(next)) });`

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n это мне не помогло. Я что-то не так сделал наверное

Comment: это пример был, вы сейчас из observable в promise через subscribe отдаёте результат, а я предложил функцией вовзращать `new Promise`, в котором уже делать subscribe и передавать его.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n честно говоря я вас не понял. Можете продемонстрировать на примере моей функции что нужно сделать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67191/discussion-between-n3r0bi0m4n-and-mirypoko).

Comment: Хочу заметить, что если где-то в компоненте посреди кода требуется выполнить нечто асинхронное (видимо сетевой запрос судя по названию) а потом дожидаться его выполнения, то в архитектуре явно что-то не так, и может вылиться во многия печали впоследствии.

Comment: @Dimanoid а как тогда делать? Мне нужно получить информацию о пользователе в компоненте. Как это сделать без запроса?

Comment: @mirypoko тогда немного подробней опишите задачу, ведь получить информацию о пользователе видимо не конечная цель? В общем случае обертка в виде Promise совершенно не нужна, а все что нужно делайте внутри `.subscribe( next => { })`

Comment: @Dimanoid я сделал регистрацию и авторизацию. О том что пользователь авторизован должны знать все компоненты, которых это касается (вроде компонентов для авторизации, регистрации, настроек пользователя) Вот код https://github.com/mirypoko/angular4test . К сожалению мне не у кого спросит правильно ли с архитектурной точки зрения я все делаю или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полистал репозиторий, чужой код конечно потёмки, но если хотите несколько мыслей вслух. На истину в высшей инстанции не претендую.

#### /src/app/app.module.ts

Для начала я бы поменял устаревший модуль `Http` на новый `HttpClient`.
https://angular.io/guide/http и добавил `HttpInterceptor` куда вынес установку нужных заголовков и т.д.

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
.....
@NgModule({
imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
.....
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
```

#### /src/app/app-routing.module.ts

Я бы из логина и регистрации сделал обычные компоненты и добавил ко всему этом `AuthGuard` https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '', component: RegisterComponent },

    // если есть админская часть можно прикрыть ее отдельным гардианом
    { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AdminAuthGuard] },

    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];
```

#### /src/app/services/users.service.ts

Я бы упростил хранение собственно юзера. `Subject` (кстати это и так Observable + Observer, соответственно `currentUserChanged$ = this._currentUserSource.asObservable();` не нужно) меняем на `BehaviorSubject` он хранит последнее значение, подписку в конструкторе убираем, она не нужна, выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
public currentUser: BehaviorSubject<IUser> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

Соответственно везде `this._currentUserSource.next` заменяем на `this.currentUser.next`, 
 а в любом компоненте где нужно инжектим сервис и:

```
usSubscription: any;
constructor(private _us: UserService) {
    let user = this._us.currentUser.getValue(); // получаем текущего юзера
    this.usSubscription = this._us.currentUser.subscribe(
        user => consoler.log('user was changed:', user);
    ); // подписываемся на логин/логаут/изменение
}
```

только не забывайте отписываться в `onDestroy`.

#### /src/app/components/authorization/authorization.component.ts

```
login() {
    this.clearFormErrors();
    if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
        this.showFormErrors(['Заполните все поля']);
        return;
    }
    this._accountService.authorizationStatus()
        .then(ok => {
            if (ok) {
                this.RedirectToHome()
            }
            else {
                let formData = this.loginForm.value;
                let login: ILogin = {
                    userName: formData.username,
                    password: formData.password,
                    rememberMe: formData.rememberMe
                };
            }
            this._accountService.login(login).subscribe(
                result => {
                    if (!result.isSucceeded) {
                        this.showFormErrors(result.messages);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        this._accountService.loadCurrentUser()
                            .then(ok => this.RedirectToHome());
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    alert(<any>error);
                    return;
                }
            );
        })
        .catch(reason => alert(<any>reason));
}
```

конечно адская смесь Promise и Observable, но это уже другая история.
И еще один момент, почти всегда можно обойтись без прямой модификации DOM,  это bad practice, если конечно вы не пишете какой-то структурную директиву или что-то очень хардкорное :)
В данном случае для показа ошибок:

```
errors: string[];
```

шаблон

```
<div *ngIf="errors" class="formErrorLable red-text">
    <ng-template ngFor let-error [ngForOf]="errors">
        {{error}}<br />
    </ng-template>
</div>
```